# Deny access to Archive.is

Tags: web-crawlers, noarchive

I would like to deny `archive.is` from having access to my website. (I do not want this website to cache mine without my consent).

Do you know if it is possible?

Answer (score 7):

Okay. This is a new one (to me at least) and quite interesting so far. I will not get into the weeds on this.

When I wrote this, I was working on little or no sleep. I missed a few things which @unor has kindly pointed out and so I must temper my answer and give credit where credit is due. Thank you @unor!

Archive.is is registered to Denis Petrov who is using a Google webhost account on IP address 104.196.7.222 [AS15169 GOOGLE - Google Inc.] according to Domain Tools though I have it on 46.17.100.191 [AS57043 HOSTKEY-AS HOSTKEY B.V.]. It is likely that the host company has recently changed.

Archive.today is also owned by Denis Petrov and is similar to Archive.is if not identical. For the purpose of this answer, I will address Archive.is and you can assume that it applies to Archive.today. Archive.today does exist on another IP address 78.108.190.21 [AS62160 GM-AS Yes Networks Unlimited Ltd]. Please understand that Denis Petrov owns 70 domains. Without digging deeper, it is possible that there are more sites to be concerned about. I will provide blocking code for all three IP addresses.

**Archive.is is user directed.** It is assumed that you are archiving your own page. Other than this scenario, Archive.is can be considered as a content scraper spam site.

**Archive.is is walking a dangerous line.** It is using other sites content through single page scraping. Ultimately, the original content's search potential is at least diluted and potentially usurped altogether. Worse yet, the original site is not cited as the originator of the content. Archive.is uses a canonical tag, but it is to it's own site/page.

Example: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://archive.is/Eo267"/>`

This coupled with the lack of controls over who is submitting a site and whether they have the right to the site, the lack of clear take-down information, and the somewhat fuzzy and potentially weak contact mechanism, Archive.is has the potential for real trouble.

You can find out more IP address information here: https://www.robtex.com/#!dns=archive.is

### How to block by IP address 78.108.190.21.

Using Cisco Firewall.

```
access-list block-78-108-190-21-32 deny ip 78.108.190.21 0.0.0.0 any
permit ip any any
```

**Note: You can replace the [provided acl name] with the ACL name of your choice.

Using Nginx.

Edit nginx.conf and insert include blockips.conf; if it does not exist. Edit blockips.conf and add the following:

```
deny 78.108.190.21/32;
```

Using Linux IPTables Firewall.
**Note: Use with caution.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 78.108.190.21/32 -j DROP
```

Using Microsoft IIS Web Server

```
<rule name="abort ip address block 78.108.190.21/32" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
   <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^78\.108\.190\.21$" />
  </conditions>
 <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Using Apache .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^78\.108\.190\.21$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

### How to block by IP address 46.17.100.191.

Using Cisco Firewall.

```
access-list block-46-17-100-191-32 deny ip 46.17.100.191 0.0.0.0 any
permit ip any any
```

**Note: You can replace the [provided acl name] with the ACL name of your choice.

Using Nginx.

Edit nginx.conf and insert include blockips.conf; if it does not exist. Edit blockips.conf and add the following:

```
deny 46.17.100.191/32;
```

Using Linux IPTables Firewall.
**Note: Use with caution.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 46.17.100.191/32 -j DROP
```

Using Microsoft IIS Web Server

```
<rule name="abort ip address block 46.17.100.191/32" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
   <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^46\.17\.100\.191$" />
  </conditions>
 <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Using Apache .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^46\.17\.100\.191$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

### How to block by IP address 104.196.7.222.

Using Cisco Firewall.

```
access-list block-104-196-7-222-32 deny ip 104.196.7.222 0.0.0.0 any
permit ip any any
```

**Note: You can replace the [provided acl name] with the ACL name of your choice.

Using Nginx.

Edit nginx.conf and insert include blockips.conf; if it does not exist. Edit blockips.conf and add the following:

```
deny 104.196.7.222/32;
```

Using Linux IPTables Firewall.
**Note: Use with caution.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 104.196.7.222/32 -j DROP
```

Using Microsoft IIS Web Server

```
<rule name="abort ip address block 104.196.7.222/32" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
   <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^104\.196\.7\.222$" />
  </conditions>
 <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Using Apache .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^104\.196\.7\.222$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

You may need to block more than one IP address from any set of code. That is not clear.

Comment: Very informative! I 100% agree with you, but I'm afraid this website uses more IP addresses. You notice this when you archive a page providing the IP of the visitor (like wtfismyip.com/). So far I have found: 2a01:4f8:190:5388::2:2,
2a01:4f8:190:6388::2:2,
2a01:4f8:190:638c::2:2,
46.17.100.191,
78.46.174.144,
78.108.190.21,
104.196.7.222

Comment: Another one: 2a01:4f8:190:6396::2:2. I would like to block all IPv6 addresses beginning with "2a01:4f8:190:". Do you know how I could do that? Thank you!

Comment: When I faced this problem a year ago, I emailed Denis a copyright takedown notice to webmaster-at-archive-dot-is and was pleasantly surprised to see all offending content removed the next day. Was just going to post this as another answer, but I checked his site and see my content is back up! I now have solid  proof of knowing, wilful copyright infringement. Ah well, IPTables it is then. He was with OVH last year and they've been very helpful with past issues, not sure where he's hosted just now though.

Comment: Also, see this related Q&A from Superuser last January: http://superuser.com/a/868368 (note different IPs used then, so this will require constantly monitoring and updating your blocklist to remain effective...).

Comment: @TomBrossman Thanks for the info! I could not sleep last night and so far only got 3 hours. To that end, when I am more awake, I will attack this again and see what else I can find.

Comment: @someone2332 I am sure that there have been several IP addresses over the past months years. You will have to monitor the IP addresses somewhat closely to know what to block. Sucks, but it is part of doing business on the web these days. Fortunately, blocking scrapers does have an effect. Just this year several really bad ones have given up and gone away.

Comment: We could perhaps set up a webpage sharing these IPs, what do you think?

Comment: "Archive.org, which is a similar site, has been sued many times and lost" To which cases do you refer? Google `archive.org loses copyright lawsuit` didn't seem to turn up relevant articles about rulings.

Comment: @tepples Quite a few are listed on wikipedia - or at least they were. You can at least start with The Grateful Dead. If you look harder than one search, you will find several.

Comment: @someone2332 This, in part, was what my site is supposed to be about. However, with needed changes to the schema to convert quite a few of the 70+ tables from static references to fully referential leaf tables, I cannot make historical, periodical, and current data available (only at time of capture). I may be revamping the schema and the site or just plain dropping the whole *bad boy* list altogether since Google thinks it is another spammy whois site instead of what it is intended to be - confirmation and research of abuse. I use my tools here all the time - for example, the blocking code.

Comment: @someone2332 BTW- I added a rant at Google in he answer that I am sure will get me de-listed by sunset. Google, for the record, you do fantastic things, I do understand the difficulty and appreciate the work, however, this has gotten beyond even my boiling point which is very high. My apologies. But something is amiss.

Comment: @TomBrossman OVH, helpful? They are spammers’ heaven and don’t react *at all* to abuse complaints. It was bad enough that OVH almost got depeered by several European ISPs (I have an inside source). I block the entire OVH network ranges on my firewalls. A friend has statistics, OVH is worse than the entirety of China, wrt. spam.

Comment: "Archive.today is also owned by Denis Petrov and is similar to Archive.is if not identical." - `archive.today` appears to 301 redirect to `archive.is`? In fact, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive.is) `archive.today` was its former home. FWIW Google does appear to be "well aware" of `archive.is`... at least I can't seem to find any `archive.is` shortened URLs in "normal" Google SERPs. (?) Only if I specifically do a `site:archive.is` search (which is a very different kind of search) can I find these URLs.

Comment: @w3d More valid points. I did not mean that .is and ,today both hosted similar or identical content, but in all other respects are identical. I found some pages on in that referred to today. At the time I wrote that, I was looking at domain tools which has older information. my tools and robtex are the only sites that had accurate information. I did not think about Wikipedia! I was sure that these pages did not rank, however, my rant, fair or not, was whether the pages should be listed at all - at least in my mind. I will remove the rant... in a bit... ;-) Cheers!

Comment: @mirabilos My comment about OVH referred to their copyright and takedown policies which are fine, they take appropriate action when I provide notice of infringement. Shame about the spam though. I've not seen the same results as you. My email address is public and 100% of the spam I see is SEO garbage from GMail users, never anything from OVH. They are also a huge provider here in Europe and blocking their network range is impractical for me - too many legitimate visitors would be cut off.

Answer (score 3):

#### `robots.txt`

[Archive.is](http://archive.is/) does not use a bot that autonomously crawls pages (e.g., by following hyperlinks), so `robots.txt` does not apply, because it’s always a user that gives the command to archive a certain page.

For the same reason, services like Google’s Feedfetcher ([Why isn't Feedfetcher obeying my robots.txt file?](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178852?hl=en#robots)) and W3C’s Validator ([details](https://validator.w3.org/services#blocking)) don’t obey `robots.txt`.

See the archive.is FAQ: [*Why does archive.is not obey robots.txt?*](http://archive.is/faq#Why_does_archive_is_not_obey_robots_txt_)

#### `meta`-`robots` / `X-Robots-Tag`

I’m not sure if archive.is should (ideally) honor the `noindex` or `noarchive` value in `meta`-`robots`/`X-Robots-Tag`, or if these technologies also apply to autonomous bots only. But as archive.is doesn’t document it, they don’t seem to support it currently.

(FWIW, each archived pages seem to get a `<meta name="robots" content="index,noarchive"/>`.)

#### `User-Agent`

archive.is doesn’t document that a certain `User-Agent` is used (they probably don’t identify themselves, to get the pages as if viewed by a usual browser), so you can’t use it to block their access on the server-level.

#### Blocking their IP addresses

So as neither `robots.txt` nor `meta`-`robots` / `X-Robots-Tag` work here, and you can’t block them via their `User-Agent`, you would have to block accesses from archive.is IPs. See [closetnoc’s answer about IP blocking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/88262/17633), but note that this might block more than intended, and you might never catch all of their IPs (and/or keep up to date).

#### Side note: Report function

Each archived version links to a form where you can report possible abuse (append `/abuse`), e.g., with the reasons "SEO Issue" or "Copyright". But I don’t know if or how they handle these cases.

Comment: I was working on no or little sleep and fully missed a few things that you rightly point out. As a result, I tempered my answer. Duh! I did get a little carried away as I sometimes can do. ;-) Ooopppsss!! It is still a bit over the top. I appreciate your answer here. I wish I could up-vote to make this the top answer. I advise people to vote for this answer with their mouse if they agree with my sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

To block the disgusting stealing practices of archive.is (ignoring robots.txt, overriding link canonical, fake user agent, no way to perform a site-wide removal), I want to add the following to the solutions above.

## Find their IP-addresses

To find their ip-addresses, submit a url to them that is under your control so that you can monitor your web server logs to see who accessed it that url. The url doesn't even have to exist, as long as the web server receives the request. (So it is better to use a non-existing empty page/url.) For example, use an url like: http://example.com/fuck-you-archive.is

Then check your logs to see who accessed the url. You can use grep to check it:

```
grep "fuck-you-archive.is" web-server-log.txt
```

Once you have the IP-address, you can block it using the solutions from the other answers. And then repeat the process again to find other IP-addresses they use. You need to specify a different url, to make them perform a HTTP request again, for example, simply change http://example.com/fuck-you-archive.is to http://example.com/fuck-you-archive.is?2 etc.

In case you don't want to expose your website at all when trying to find their IP-addresses, you may want to use this handy HTTP request website: https://requestb.in The steps to perform are: create a RequestBin > submit the "BinURL" to Archive.is with "?SomeRandomNumber" appended to the BinURL > use the "?inspect" of RequestBin to monitor the incoming request from Archive.is and see their IP-address in the "Cf-Connecting-Ip" HTTP header. (Make sure you don't submit "?inspect" url to Archive.is.) Than repeat to find other IP-addresses by changing "?SomeRandomNumber" to another number.

## Block their ip addresses

Note that with IP-tables you can block using

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 78.108.190.21 -j DROP
```

but often the 'INPUT' chain is set to a 'DROP' policy with acceptance of HTTP traffic. In that case, you may need to use a prepend (insert) operation instead of append operation, otherwise it isn't blocked at all:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 78.108.190.21 -j DROP
```

However, they have alot of IP-addresses, so it may be easier to block complete IP-ranges. You can do this conveniently with IPTables (without the need to specify subnetmasks) using:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m iprange --src-range 46.166.139.110-46.166.139.180 -j DROP
```

This range (46.166.139.110-46.166.139.180) is for a large part owned by them, because I have seen multiple addresses between 46.166.139.110 and 46.166.139.173.

## Send an abuse complaint to their web host

They are currently using NFOrce as web host. See https://www.nforce.com/abuse to how to make a complaint about Archive.is.
Mention: 1) your webpage url that archive.is has stolen, 2) mention the url at archive.is that contains the stolen content, and 3) mention the IP-addresses that they used.

Also you may want to complain at Cloudflare, their CDN, which caches their stolen pages and images for performance reasons. https://www.cloudflare.com/abuse/

Answer (score 1):

As we can see, archive.is is using DNS anycasting.

If you use different nameservers (e.g. from https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062) you currently (2018-09-10) get different ip addresses for "archive.is" (dig @NAMESERVER archive.is A)

```
104.27.170.40
104.27.171.40
154.59.112.68
185.219.42.148
46.105.75.102
46.17.42.43
46.182.19.43
46.45.185.30
80.211.3.180
81.7.17.119
91.121.82.32
91.219.236.183
94.16.117.236
```

I used abuse-contacts.abusix.org (https://www.abusix.com/contactdb) to get the abuse contacts for these ip addresses:

```
abuse@as42926.net
abuse@cloudflare.com
abuse@cogentco.com
abuse@isppro.de
abuse@nbiserv.de
abuse@netcup.de
abuse@ovh.net
abuse@serverastra.com
abuse@staff.aruba.it
abuseto@adminvps.ru
noc@baxet.ru
```

As Cloudflare reported, archive.is is abusing their "services" by using a DNS A-record which has no functionality!

Answer (score 0):

Also consider Contacting the registrars at www.isnic.is, Iceland's Domain Registry. 
isnic at isnic dot is

Iceland has copyright law, and the Registry recognizes it.
The Registry has existed since the late 1980s, and is not under ICANN.